# Test func can't read environment from launch.json | Golang | VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to read os the environment in my Test Func. I have added the variable `launch .json`. When I run or debug the test, the env values are empty.

Please see the conf file below:

File Name : `launch.json`

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {
                "HI": "Hi from env!"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried `mode="test"`, but the same result.

My test file: `main_test.go`
package: `main_test`

```
package main_test

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func Test_hi(t *testing.T) {
    hi := os.Getenv("HI")
    _ = hi
    t.Fail()
    t.Log("Hello from test. ", hi)
}
```

I am running or debugging my test by clicking on the button as seen in the below screenshot: `line number 8` (**run test | debug test**)

[image: main_test.go]

- Terminal output (When I click on run test):

[image: run test]

- Terminal output (When I click on debug test):

[image: debug test]

- Go version : `go version go1.20.7 linux/amd64`
- VSCode Version:

```
Version: 1.81.0
Commit: 6445d93c81ebe42c4cbd7a60712e0b17d9463e97
Date: 2023-08-02T12:36:11.334Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.19.0-50-generic
```

- dlv version

```
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.20.2
Build: $Id: e0c278ad8e0126a312b553b8e171e81bcbd37f60
```

I think this is not a Golang problem but a VSCode conf problem. I must be doing something very silly. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I can confirm that it's not a Go issue. I'm not used to VS Code but my guess would be that `${fileDirname}` doesn't match the test file you're running.

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/use-environment-variable-in-your-next-golang-project-39e17c3aaa66

Comment: It is strange. When I am pressing F5 from inside the test func it is working. Although the run and debug buttons in line 8 as shown in the above screen are still not working.

Comment: I am also facing same issue . not able to read env .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by creating the file `.vscode/settings.json`.

Here is the sample content of the file.

```json
{
    "go.testEnvVars": {
        "HI": "Hello from test env"
    },
    "go.testFlags": ["-v", "-count=1"]
}
```